# facebox overlay clash?

Tags: jquery, facebox

I use facebox for my site and when I hit "post comment", it brings up the stuff, but i think it's clashing with the navigation?  Here's the image:

[image]

it's over on the page: http://www.krissales.com/#/media/17.Testing-Article-1

hit post comment, and see what it does. I'm not sure if it's my navigation, or it's facebox.

I also think it has something to do with my core.js file, because it's so damn terrible, haha!

Comment: fyi, facebox is a terrible plugin, its a shame its has such a high ranking. its old, and the code is garbage. i suggest you find something else

Comment: yeah, i liked it at first. But I actually like prettyBox too. I dislike all the other libs though. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only problem of this is you lack of z-index..

Try to put z-index:10000 in your #facebox.

Like this:

```
#facebox{
z-index:10000
}
```

It will solve your problem..
Cheers.